# Change UITableViews depending on phone orientation

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview, landscape-portrait

I have a `UITableViewController` that is the initial controller for the application called `LoginTableViewController`.

I want to show one `UITableView` for *portrait mode* and another for *landscape mode*.

Currently I have another `UITableViewController` (`LoginTableViewController_L`) set up for landscape mode. I declared the `UITableView` from the landscape `UITableViewController` in `LoginTableViewController` hoping that I could switch `UITableViews` depending on the orientation. After rotating the phone I just get a black/blank screen with the title bar on top.

Is there a better way to approach this?

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *LoginTableView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *LoginTableView_Landscape;
```

Comment: In terms of "a better way", why not use the same table view with appropriate layout adjustments for the different orientations?

Comment: Seems like either your tableview datasource/delegates are not connected OR some issue with Autosizing..

Comment: I wanted to have a different layout for landscape view. I don't think that I can accomplish that with layout adjustments.

Comment: @BrianKalski Are the data sources connected for BOTH table views?

Comment: Should the datasources for both views be set to the UITableViewController that I am trying to display them in?

Answer (score 1):

Use a single TableView.

If you want a completely different look (not just the same cells resized)

Detect the device orientation and load different cells based on current orientation.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UIInterfaceOrientation interfaceOrientation = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation];

    if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(interfaceOrientation)) {

        PortraitCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil)
        {
            cell = [[PortraitCell alloc]init];
        }

    } else {

        LandscapeCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil)
        {
            cell = [[LandscapeCell alloc]init];
        }
    }

    return cell;
}
```

When the device orientation changes call

```
[myTableView reloadData];
```

*PsudoCode to show the concept.